# Как правильно записать текст введенный в QLineEdit в файk .txt

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

Требуется записать текст, введенный пользователем в файл. 
Я использую поле `lineEdit`, для ввода данных.

В коде это представлено так:

```
self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

И теперь, то что ввел пользователь из этой переменной мне нужно передать в другую часть кода, которая отвечает за запись в текстовый файл.

Весь код выглядит так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def clicked(self):
        file = open("file.txt", "w")
        file.write('''Ваш текст - ''' + self.lineEdit + '''''')

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(318, 77)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 111, 81))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 30, 93, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите текст:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я пытался передать значение при помощи функции `get`

```
self.lineEdit_seconds.get()
```

но результата это не принесло.

Кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой буду благодарен за решение.

Comment: Не совсем понятна ваша проблема, но может быть вам надо отлавливать событие `"Ввод"`

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @alexander-chernin проще говоря, текст введеный пользователем в поле LineEdit должен быть записан в текстовом документе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

> [**text**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) : QString
>
> Это свойство содержит текст редактирования строки.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(380, 77)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 111, 81))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 30, 150, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите текст:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Записать текст в файл."))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)        

    def clicked(self):
        if not self.lineEdit.text():
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Вы ничего не ввели, записывать нечего.'
            )
            return
            
        file_name = "file.txt"
        with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(f'Ваш текст - {self.lineEdit.text()}')

        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            'Успех', 
            f'Введенные данные записаны в файл {file_name}.'
        )        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если по мимо текста будут введены символы и цифры, программа сможет работать с ними?

Comment: @Wacihil если у вас возникли другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Wacihil я не знаю, о какой программе вы говорите. Просто скопируйте мой пример и запустите его.